# Can ColdFusion CFScript code be written using CF tags?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I am using ColdFusion 11 and found an article with a very nice example of what I need. The problem is I am better using cf tags rather than cfscript.

This code uses cfscript in components. My question is can I use cf tags in a cfc and just use cfclient as it shows in the example and it will work as expected?

http://blogs.coldfusion.com/post.cfm/cfinventory-mobile-application

Comment: FWIW, example forgot to `var` scope the funciton local varialbes in his funcitons. For example, `var q = queryExecute()` or just avoid defining the varialbe and just `return queryExecute()`.

Comment: They also forgot to scope the arguments and use query parameters. Bad Adobe..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it would work the same.

So, for example

```
component client="true" output="false" {    
    public function getStatus(id)
       {
          q = queryExecute("select * FROM status where id = '#id#'", 
                null, {"datasource"="cfds"});       
          return q;
        }   
    public function getStatusByType(type)
        {
        // always include type 0 status as they are global
        q = queryExecute("select * from status where type = '#type#' 
               or type = 0", null, {"datasource"="cfds"});       
               return q;
        }
}
```

Would be

```
<cfcomponent>
    <cffunction name="getStatus">
         <cfargument name="id">
         <cfquery name="q" datasource="cfds>
             select * FROM status where id = '#id#'
         </cfquery>
         <cfreturn q>
    </cffunction>
    <cffunction name="getStatusByType">
        <cfargument name="id" datasource="cfds>
         <cfquery name="q" datasource="cfds">
             select * from status where type = '#type#' 
           or type = 0
         </cfquery>
         <cfreturn q>
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

One thing I would improve on the code above is using cfqueryparam. Just in case.

Comment: i know that, thanks for this but my question is instead of converting the code, can i use cftags instead of cfscript

Comment: Do you mean custom tags (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0b2e1-7fff.html)?

Comment: no coldfusion tags like cfcomponent and cfscript tags

Comment: Yes, you can use them

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Jacks answer...

In ColdFusion you have the following options for CFCs, 1)  cfscript only, 2) tags only and 3) tags with cfscript blocks

**Script**

This works in new versions of ColdFusion and is good for controllers and models. This type of code is also useful for collaborating with Java and C# developers because it looks familiar to them.

Note that the `<cfscript>` does not appear in the code. ColdFusion just fugures out that this is a pure `<cfscript>` file.

```
component client="true" output="false" {    
public function getStatus(id)
   {
      q = queryExecute("select * FROM status where id = '#id#'", 
            null, {"datasource"="cfds"});       
      return q;
    }   
public function getStatusByType(type)
    {
    // always include type 0 status as they are global
    q = queryExecute("select * from status where type = '#type#' 
           or type = 0", null, {"datasource"="cfds"});       
           return q;
    }
}
```

**Tags**
This works in older versions of ColdFusion and is like to to be the most common.

```
<cfcomponent>
<cffunction name="getStatus">
     <cfargument name="id">
     <cfquery name="q" datasource="cfds>
         select * FROM status where id = '#id#'
     </cfquery>
     <cfreturn q>
</cffunction>
<cffunction name="getStatusByType">
    <cfargument name="id" datasource="cfds>
     <cfquery name="q" datasource="cfds">
         select * from status where type = '#type#' 
       or type = 0
     </cfquery>
     <cfreturn q>
</cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

**Tags with Script**

In older versions of ColdFusion, not all tags had a script equivalent. For this reason we often had to toggle in and out of `<cfscript>` mode. This good part of this approach is that code can be converted as needed.

```
<cfcomponent>
<cffunction name="getStatus">
     <cfargument name="id">
     <cfquery name="q" datasource="cfds>
         select * FROM status where id = '#id#'
     </cfquery>
     <cfreturn q>
</cffunction>

<cfscript>
public function getStatusByType(type)
    {
    // always include type 0 status as they are global
    q = queryExecute("select * from status where type = '#type#' 
           or type = 0", null, {"datasource"="cfds"});       
           return q;
    }
</cfscript>
</cfcomponent>
```